# Springboot slow after many saves

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I create one springboot app to migrate one old base to a new, but I get a test, and migrate only 2 years (190k registers) so after migrate +/- 140k the time to save are huge, there is any way to improve this, for every save clear something ? I have a log of saves to migrate one register, so I try in the last use the saveAndFlush but dont work, and I already try to paginate to without success

tks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32066898/jpa-2-0-how-to-improve-performance-on-bulk-insertion-through-jpa (which is basically a duplicate of this question).

Answer (score 0):

It could happen when e.g. there are a lot of data in one transaction. You should split the migration somehow.

You can add [Spring Batch](https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/) job to do the migrations by chunks.

Or read data once and when processing commit every let say 100 inserts.